# Aws boto3 redshift client wait until sql executes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, boto3

```
client = boto3.client('redshift-data')

# this seems asynchronous 
response = client.execute_statement(
    ClusterIdentifier='xyz',
    Database='dev',
    DbUser='user1',
    Sql='select * from table1;',
    StatementName='test1',
    WithEvent=False
)

describe = client.describe_statement(Id=response['Id'])
print(describe['Status'])  # PICKED, SUBMITTED
```

After executing a sql, it takes some time to get the final response.

Especially when sql = `vacuum table1;`
Without any waiting mechanism, the status returned is `PICKED` or `SUBMITTED`.

Are there any redshift waiters like [these](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift.html#waiters) , or do I need to manually wait until the status changes to `FAILED` or `SUCCESS`

Comment: The waiters are nothing else then  a loop which pulls for status with 15 seconds intervals. You have to implement it yourself for your use-case.